# Can a single core of a cpu process more than one process?

Tags: cpu, multithreading

This is the reasoning for my question: I read this in a text book 
“Each CPU (or core) can be working on one process at a time.”

I'm assuming that this used to be accurate but is no longer fully true. How does multi threading play into this? Or is this still true, can a cpu core on linux still only work on one process at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single CPU handles one process at a time. But a "process" is a construct of an operating system; the OS calls playing a video in VLC a single process, but it's actually made up of lots of individual instructions. So it's not as if a CPU is tasked with playing a video and has to drop everything it was doing. A CPU can take on the task of playing a video → switch over to checking for keyboard or mouse input → draw some stuff on the screen → check to see if devices have been attached in any known port → and so on. All within the blink of an eye.

Modern computers excel at multi-tasking. This is why you can launch a video in VLC and have it play continuously even though your computer is doing 100 other odd jobs "at the same time".

Comment: It uses time slicing: the OS is woken up by an alarm ever so often, it then switches to a different thread/process/task.

Comment: Should SMT ("hyperthreading") be considered running several tasks simultaneously on a single core? Also, perhaps it would be best to rephrase to say "core" instead of "CPU"?

Comment: Each time the CPU switches tasks (e.g. from displaying a video frame to updating mouse position) there is the risk that all or part of the CPU caches _do_ get dropped, though. Just like you or I can only hold several digits in our working memory at once, so is it with microprocessors (although they can remember many more digits than we can).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that a *single threaded* process (program) will be constrained to execution on a single CPU core even if its running on a system with a multi-core CPU.
If a processes is multithreaded  and its running on a system with a multi-core CPU, the execution of individual threads can be handed off to different CPU cores and therefore the program can benefit from parallel processing.
I think when muliti-core CPU's first appeared in the early 2000's alot of programs still had a single threaded architecture and therefore saw no performance benefit from the muliti-core CPU's.
Although the system overall could benefit as it could run other processes on the the other CPU cores.

Comment: This is the answer to the opposite question “can a single thread run over many cores?” not “can a single core run may threads?”